# .NET Core 3 System.Text.Json nested object serialization

Tags: .net, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, system.text.json

Just playing with new [System.Text.Json](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) using VS2019 web application template:

Having weather forecast class declaration as:

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication4
{
    public class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
        public string Summary { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example method:

```
 [HttpGet("Test1")]
    public WeatherForecast Test1()
    {
        WeatherForecast forecast = new WeatherForecast();
        return forecast;
    }
```

This works ok, returned: 
*{"date":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","temperatureC":0,"temperatureF":32,"summary":null}*

But this code:

```
 public class TestClass
    {
        public WeatherForecast Forecast;
    }

    [HttpGet("Test")]
    public TestClass Test()
    {
        WeatherForecast forecast = new WeatherForecast();
        TestClass test = new TestClass()
        {
            Forecast = forecast
        };
        return test;
    }
```

returns emply json object: *{}*

How to serialize nested objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use properties probably fields won't serialise. Add get and set to forecast.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public WeatherForecast Forecast {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Exact same problem. Missed getters and setters on one model. Was pulling my hair out. Thank you!